# Android checkbox not inflated as MaterialCheckBox as stated in documentation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-checkbox

I'm trying to following the documentation from Material 3 for checkboxes:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Checkbox.md

At the very beginning it states:

> Note: `<CheckBox>` is auto-inflated as
> `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialCheckBox>` via
> `MaterialComponentsViewInflater` when using a `Theme.Material3.*`
> theme.

**This does not seem to work for me, can someone please explain why the checkbox is not auto-inflated as a MaterialCheckBox?**

Both theme files are using: `Theme.Material3.*`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ParentChildCheckboxes" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ParentChildCheckboxes" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_child_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_child_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_child_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_child_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_child_1" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_child_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_child_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_child_2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_child_4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_child_4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_child_3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity file:

```
package com.example.parentchildcheckboxes

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.parentchildcheckboxes.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox.STATE_INDETERMINATE

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val checkBoxParent = binding.checkboxParent
        checkBoxParent.checkedState = STATE_INDETERMINATE
    }
}
```

I cant use `.checkedState` on `checkBoxParent` because it's not treated as a `MaterialCheckBox`:

When I hover on the `val checkBoxParent` , I see: `val checkBoxParent: CheckBox` and expected: `val checkBoxParent: MaterialCheckBox`.

When I change: `val checkBoxParent = binding.checkboxParent` to: `val checkBoxParent = binding.checkboxParent as MaterialCheckBox`:

```
    val checkBoxParent = binding.checkboxParent as MaterialCheckBox
    checkBoxParent.checkedState = STATE_INDETERMINATE
```

it works fine.

**Why is the checkbox not auto-inflated as a MaterialCheckBox? as stated in the documentation?**

Comment: It is being inflated as a `MaterialCheckBox`; that's why you can cast it as such without a crash. That substitution is happening at runtime, though, and if you were to inflate that layout in a plain `Activity`, you would end up with plain old `CheckBox`es. The binding class only knows what you tell it in the layout file, and you've specified simply `<CheckBox>`es there, so that's how it declares them. If you'd rather the binding class declare them as `MaterialCheckBox`es, that's what you'll need to specify in the layout XML.

Comment: What confuses me is that the documentation specifically tells you to use `com.google.android.material.*` for other components but for checkboxes all their examples are `<CheckBox>`. Why didn't they use: `com.google.android.material.MaterialCheckBox` in the example documentation for Material 3 checkboxes? I'm using: `com.google.android.material.MaterialCheckBox` now in the layout file and continue to explore the parent/child relationship example.

Comment: Only certain tags are automatically substituted with newer library classes; mostly the basics like `<Button>`,  `<TextView>`, etc. Other classes like `TextInputLayout` never existed before the library, though, so there are no corresponding "plain" tags for them to substitute in for. After a quick look through the linked docs, it looks like they only use the full name tags where necessary. Those docs weren't really written with data binding in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `<CheckBox>` tag to: `<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox>` solved the issue for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_child_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_child_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_child_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_child_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_child_1" />

    <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_child_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_child_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_child_2" />

    <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_child_4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/label_child_4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkbox_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_child_3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```